# Rails database design with or without associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, database-design

Question about database design with Rails.

I wanted to know if I'm on the right track or if I'm making things overtly complicated.

Scenario: A list of companies that displays:

- Company name
- Bio
- Website address
- Email
- Phone number
- Address
- Social Media Links

I thought it would a good idea to create 4 models backed by a database.

- Companies
- Numbers (a company can have multiple phone numbers (land, fax, pager)
- Addresses (a company can have multiple locations)
- Links (social media: The Facebook, Google, LinkedIn

I have two questions.

1. Is it okay to simply have 1 table that contains all the fields and keep on adding to it if required eg. new social media website. Is this bad practise?

---

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Table name = Companies
  # name     :string
  # bio      :text
  # url      :string
  # email    :string
  # phone    :string
  # Location information
  # address1 :string
  # address2 :string
  # city     :string
  # state    :string
  # postcode :string
  # country  :string
  # Social media links
  # facebook :string
  # google   :string
  # linkedin :string
end
```

---

2. Would breaking it up like the following make for best practice, is there any performance benefits setting it up this would with foreign keys / has_many, belongs_to associations?

---

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Table name = Companies
 # name     :string
 # bio      :text
 # url      :string
 # email    :string
 # phone    :string

  has_many :locations
  has_many :social_media_links
end

class Number < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Table name = Numbers
  number      :string
  company_id  :integer

  belongs_to :company
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Table name = Locations
  # address1     :string
  # address2     :string
  # city         :string
  # state        :string
  # postcode     :string
  # country      :string
  # company_id   :integer

  belongs_to :company

  # I presume, you could also create a Country and State model
  # and create a has_many and belongs_to associations, 
  # to allow for selections like in a dropdown box?
end

class SocialMediaLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Table name = SocialMediaLinks
  name        :string
  url:        :string
  company_id  :integer

  belongs_to :company
end
```

---

Thanks for reviewing this question. Also, if there are Rails open source project that you can suggest to learn and look at how they designed their database / active record associations, please let me know.

Comment: It is best to split the data, as storing it all together would mean duplicating data for many columns. Especially if you expect large volumes of data to store. However if the database is going to deal with only 4, or 5 companies splitting data might not be worth the effort.

Comment: No it's not best to split the data - it's entirely dependent on the scope of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to know if I'm on the right track

You are, it's a valid question.

The biggest determinant of how you'd structure the data would have to come from the scope of the application.

If you're expecting a `Company` to have multiple `locations`, `social media profiles` etc, then *yes*, you would be best splitting the data. If you were only expecting companies to have singular data, then you'd just be causing yourself more problems than its worth.

---

**Extensibility**

> keep on adding to it if required

What's you're looking for is *[extensibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensibility)* - the ability to add data to your system as required.

If you have a company with rigid data structure, you'd do well having a single model/table. If you wanted to add extra fields (new `social` accounts etc), the correct practice is to use the multi-model approach. Technically, there is nothing wrong with either.

--

The best thing I would recommend would be to embed nested models into *modules*:

```
#app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations, class_name: "Company::Location", dependent: :destroy
end

#app/models/company/location.rb
class Company::Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

You should only create the dependent models *if* you have the need to add extra records / data for the aforementioned models.

Comment: Hi @rick-peck, thank you for taking the time in responding to my question. I would love to read more about embed nested models into modules as your detailed, is there documentation or a blog post you can point me to read and learn more? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Hey buddy, I've not got any resources at hand. I could write about it if you wanted more info. It's really similar to the `namespace` idea in your routes. Indeed, you can define a ["module" for your controllers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) in the routes